# Python - how to make loop continue after Try Catch?

Tags: python, iteration

I have following python code and it works fine but it brings error and then jumps to the last line.
Then I remove problematic line from a file, run again python script but it again finds problematic line and jumps to the end. 
I want to be able to print all lines without jumping to the end of python script (just skip line and continue to the next):

```
import csv
with open('data.tsv', "rb") as f:
    reader = csv.reader( f )

    try:
        for row in reader:
            continue
    except csv.Error, e:
        print reader.line_num, e
        pass
print "End of file!\n"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

iterate manually, hoping that the csv reader object can recover from the exception:

```
import csv
with open('data.tsv', "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader( f )

    while True:
        try:
           row = next(reader)
           print(row)
        except csv.Error as e:
           print("line: {}, error: {}".format(reader.line_num, e))
        except StopIteration:
            break
    print("End of file!\n")
```

the `StopIteration` exception is raised when `csv.reader` object reaches the end of file. At this point, `break` is used to exit from the infinite loop.

Let's test this by inserting a NULL byte in a row. An easy way is to replace `f` by a list of rows:

```
data = """hello,world
foo,bar
hi\x00,I'm joe
recovered,yeah
"""

f = data.splitlines()
```

now `f` can be fed to `csv.reader` with the code above (remove `with` block). Note the NUL byte inserted at the third line. Output:

```
['hello', 'world']
['foo', 'bar']
line: 3, error: line contains NULL byte
['recovered', 'yeah']
End of file!
```

yeah! it works (and the code is compatible with Python 2 and Python 3 as a bonus)

Comment: "hoping that the csv reader object can recover from the exception" is an interesting point. It's possible to get an exception here that just gives a dead reader after? Is this as in, the syntax or whatever that caused the issue just cascades to the next rows?

Comment: I suppose that you can lose the reader with sufficiently corrupt data :) then you get exception after exception.

Comment: Ok, I follow. It doesn't corrupt the object, just an issue that keeps erroring on every subsequent line. For some reason I had something more elaborate in my mind when I read that line :P

Comment: it's useful, when a line contains a nul byte for instance.

Answer (score -2):

Move the `try`  inside the for loop

```
import csv
with open('data.tsv', "rb") as f:
    reader = csv.reader( f )
for row in reader:
    try:
            continue
    except csv.Error, e:
        print reader.line_num, e
        pass
print "End of file!\n"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, your `try` can never fail... `for row in reader` is throwing the exception.